# How do I create a C++ library in VS 2008?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, dll

I am working in VS 2008 and have several C++ projects and want to build my own library to share across projects. The first project is called "Project 1".

I created the library as a separate Win 32 project, and chose DLL. I added a reference in Project 1 to the library using "Add reference". I also added an "Additional reference search path". I added #include "Library.h" to the top of the cpp file for Project 1.

However, I am getting the error: fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'Library.h': No such file or directory.

How do I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Placing quotes been Library.h signifies that the library is in the local directory of your Project.  This is not the case, since multiple projects will be requiring that library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the projects are in separate folders, you may have you do something like:

```
#include "../libproject/Library.h"
```

Answer (score 2):

In Visual C++'s terms, referencing a project does not add it to include search path (this is a paradigm shift from .NET). Because in C++, `include` can do all sorts of things -- you can even `#include <not_even_a_c_file.txt>`, for example.

Anyway, the quick solution for you is to also add the include path to Project 1. You can find it under Project Properties > C++ > General. You need to add the path to Project 2 under "Additional Include Directories".